# Sending mp3 over http chunked encoding in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, chunked-encoding, http-chunked

Hi I'm trying to send mp3 data over http with chucked encoding. The idea is that the mp3 will later be a live stream (of mp3 pieces) so I don't know what the content length will be.

Here is my code which isn't playable when I access with a browser.... although it recognises the header file file won't play at all.

Anyone have any ideas where i'm going wrong?

```
 Private Sub ServeAudioBlock(stream As NetworkStream)

    Dim Content As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("tone.mp3")

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + ControlChars.CrLf)
    sb.Append("Content-Type: audio/mpeg" + ControlChars.CrLf)
    sb.Append("Transfer-Encoding: chunked" + ControlChars.CrLf)
    sb.Append(ControlChars.CrLf)

    'send header
    Dim Header() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString)
    stream.Write(Header, 0, Header.Length)

    'send five times
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5

        'send length in hex
        Dim SizeString As String = Hex(Content.Length)
        Dim chunksize() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(SizeString + ControlChars.CrLf)
        stream.Write(chunksize, 0, chunksize.Length)

        'send data for this chunk
        stream.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length)

    Next


    Dim EmptyChunk As String = "0" + ControlChars.CrLf
    Dim EmptyBytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(EmptyChunk)
    stream.Write(EmptyBytes, 0, EmptyBytes.Length)

    Console.WriteLine("Served audio block")

    stream.Close()

End Sub
```

The first few lines of the response that I'm capturing with HTTP analyzer:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

11F4
ÿûPÄ<rest of file data follows>
```

Comment: stream is the result of client.GetStream on a TcpClient object. The general http serving code is working for plain text, html, jpegs etc so I don't think the problem lies there

Comment: Think this might be a safari specific issue...